# Get return value of the Dial application in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, ivr

I call to a voice browser with the Dial application on SIP channel in Asterisk. The VXI returns a number. How can I get that number as a return value of the Dial application? `${DIALSTATUS}` doesn't get the return value. It has last result of Dial application like `ANSWER`,`NOANSWER`,... .

```
exten => _.,n,Set(VXMLFILE=/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/${EXTEN}.vxml) 
exten => _.,n,SipAddHeader(voicexml: ${VXMLFILE})
exten => _.,n,Dial(sip/[some parameters])
```

Answer (score 0):

Voicexml processing is not part of asterisk, it done by your UA.

So you have consult our UA for result.

Can suggest it allow save log on remote syslog server, so you can parse result from log.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk cannot directly parse the vxml or xml files.

Create an Asterisk AGI script and parse the vxml file and assign the value to the variable "VXMLFILE".

Go through this URL to understand how Asterisk AGI works.
[voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI)